# Duda teorica sobre recursividad en vectores

Tags: c++, array, vectores

Mi pregunta es si puede un procedimiento recursivo tener dos casos bases?
Estaba realizando un modulo que me el cual me pedia que teniendo dos vectores con valores cargados, asigne al primer vector el producto de los dos vectores, utilizando para el calculo de producto sumas sucesivas, y recursividad.
De la manera sencilla se me ocurrió hacerlo de esta manera:

```
const int MAX=7;
typedef int tvector [MAX];/*Esto lo defino al principio, no muestro el programa principal, porque es un poco largo, pero la duda estaria unicamente en ese modulo*/
void multiplicar_vec (tvector &vec1,tvector vec2){
int i;
for (i=0;i<=MAX-1;i++){
    vec1[i]=producto(vec1[i],vec2[i])
    cout<<vec[i]<<endl;
    }
cout<<endl;
}

int producto (int a, int b){
int p;
if (b==1)
    p=a;
    0
else
    p=a+producto(a,b-1);
return p;
}
```

De esta manera el modulo funcionaba, pero yo quería hacerlo todo en un modulo, y se me ocurrió esta idea:

```
void producto (tvector &vec1,tvector vec2,int a, int b, int &p,int i=MAX-1)
{
if (i==0){ //caso base para recorrer el vector
    a=vec1[i];
b=vec2[i];
        if (b==1)// caso base para realizar el producto mediante sumas sucesivas
        p=a;
        else{
        producto (vec1,vec2,a,b-1,p,i);
                    p=p+a;}
    vec1[i]=p;
   } else{
   
        producto(vec1,vec2,a,b,p,i--);
        i++;
         a=vec1[i];
b=vec2[i];
        if (b==1)
        p=a;
        else{
       producto (vec1,vec2,a,b-1,p,i);
                    p=p+a;}
        vec1[i]=p;
}
}
```

Cuando hice esto, lo realice pensando en tener dos casos bases uno para recorrer el vector y otro para hacer el producto. Cuando me compiló, surgia error, me mostraba por pantalla que el programa creado del codigo "modulo.exe" dejo de funcionar. Entonces pensé que quizas no se pueda realizar un solo modulo con dos casos bases, o el segundo modulo que realice tenga muchos errores (lo cual es muy probable).
Pero bueno, esa es mi duda. Si alguien me puede ayudar o dar su punto de vista me ayudaria bastante. Desde ya si esta leyendo esto ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Hola Nael! Bienvenido a SO en español. Dices que *Cuando me compiló, surgia error*, siempre que obtengas un error, comparte el error que obtienes y así es mucho más facil para la comunidad apoyarte. De paso date una vuelta por [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: Hola. Perdon, no cuando me compilo, sino al terminar de compilar, es decir, en la ejecucion, mostraba un cartel que la aplicacion, "modulo.exe" dejo de funcionar.

Comment: Oh ya veo y ¿Puedes compartir la definición de tu clase `tvector`?

Comment: Si typedef int tvector [MAX];.Donde MAX es constante = 7

Comment: Hay varias cosas que no entiendo. 1. ¿Porqué pides como parámetro a y b además de los vectores, estos no deberían de ser los elementos de cada vector? 2.¿Porqué llamas a la misma función dentro de ella misma **sin tener un valor de retorno**? Esta recursividad va a hacer que tu programa se quede "dando vueltas" entrando en la función de manera infinita.

Comment: Intente utilzar a y b para realizar el calculo del producto. Trate de llamar al mismo procedimiento para que se reestablezcan los valores i, y vec1. Pero tenes razón, creo que al no tener un valor exacto de retorno, se queda "dando vueltas". Me gustaria saber si es que se podria hacer un procedimiento recursivo con dos casos bases,si se puede lo sigo intentando y sino creo que lo dejare por un tiempo.

Comment: Deberías de investigar un poco sobre *iteradores*, creo que te será de gran ayuda para lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Bueno, Muchas gracias

Comment: @FranAcuna te da igual usar iteradores o índices. Ninguno de los dos te aporta una ventaja significativa sobre el otro

Comment: @eferion Esto no lo sabía, mencioné los iteradores solo como un recurso de investigación para que el OP obtuviese ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Para que una única función haga las dos cosas debe tener muy claro cuándo debe iterar por los vectores y cuando debe calcular un producto.

En el caso que acompaña esta respuesta usa `b` como variable de control ya que calcular un producto a base de sumas hace que `b` tenga que ser siempre positiva.

```
int multiplicar_vec (tvector vec1,tvector vec2, int max, int i=0, int a=-1, int b=-1)
{
    if( i < max)
    {
        if( b > 0 )
        {
            return a + multiplicar_vec(vec1, vec2, max, i, a, b-1);
        }
        else if( b < 0 )
        {
            vec1[i] = multiplicar_vec(vec1, vec2, max, i, vec1[i], vec2[i]);
            multiplicar_vec(vec1, vec2, max, i+1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```